# How to write llvm pass in Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, llvm

I built my pass on Linux and it worked there correctly. Now when I brought in my code to Mac OS X 10.9 on Mac Airbook, its not working anymore. I am describing below the steps I took for building my llvm pass.

My source tree is llvm-3.4 and llv-3.4/tools/clang-3.4

I ran `./configure --prefix=/some-path --enable-targets=host` which was successful.

Then I ran `make && make install` which completed without any errors.

I exported the bin path `export PATH=/some-path/bin:$path` and checked for `which clang` `which opt` and they pointed to my installation.

Now when I tried to load hello pass `opt -load /some-path/lib/LLVMHello.dylib -hello <fac.bc >/dev/null` I get the following error

`Error opening '/some-path/lib/LLVMHello.dylib': dlopen(/some-path/lib/LLVMHello.dylib, 9): Symbol not found: __ZN4llvm12FunctionPass17assignPassManagerERNS_7PMStackENS_15PassManagerTypeE
  Referenced from: /some-path/lib/LLVMHello.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /some-path/lib/LLVMHello.dylib
  -load request ignored.
opt: Unknown command line argument '-hello'.  Try: '/some-path/bin/opt -help'
opt: Did you mean '-help'?`

Can someone help me fix this issue or at least point in the right direction.

Comment: Did you solve this issue on mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the dynamic LLVM library, which is required for dynamically loaded passes, was missing. I solved it by configuring LLVM with --enable-shared. I also had --enable-keep-symbols set, but I don't think this is necessary. The full configure command I used:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-keep-symbols
```

I know I'm a bit late with the answer, but I recently ran into the same problem. And since I spent quite some time solving the issue, I wanted to pass on my findings. Hope it helps.

Cheers, Marcus

Comment: LLVM does not support `./configure ` anymore. How do you pass `KEEP_SYMBOLS` with `cmake`?